# How do you unset the ngSrc directive?

Tags: angularjs

I am using [ngSrc](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) to change the src attribtue of an iframe.

```
<iframe ng-src={{url}}></iframe>
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.npr.org");
```

This works fine. I can even change the it to another url and it works fine.

```
// some time later...
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.nasa.gov");
```

But what doesn't work is when I try to change it to an empty string. Then it does nothing.

```
$scope.url = ""; // this doesnt work
$scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(""); // this doesn't work
```

I need for the src attribute to be an empty string. How do I do that with AngularJS? [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqDiZkk4c0DPoKdSLQpL?p=preview) is my Plunkr.

Comment: Why not simply hide the `iframe`

Comment: I do, actually. But when I go to the next url I fade the iframe back in. When the iframe is being faded in you can see the content from the old url. So right after I hide it I want to make sure src=""

Comment: How about setting it to `about:blank`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I was just about to post that as an answer: $scope.url = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("about:blank");

Comment: about:blank worked! If you post an answer I will mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting src to [about:blank](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6694#page-3) works in your plunker, and is now an "[IANA officially registered scheme, and is standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/About_URI_scheme)".